# How can I locate opcode header files in this prebuilt RISC-V toolchain?

Tags: riscv

How to add custom instructions to prebuilt riscv toolchain?

I've tried to build an riscv gnu toolchain from [an original source](https://github.com/riscv-collab/riscv-gnu-toolchain), but after realizing that I don't have the necessary disk space/time for that, I rather resorted to using [the prebuilt version](https://github.com/stnolting/riscv-gcc-prebuilt) (`rv64imc-3.0.0`).

I want to add some custom instructions to the Binutils, which requires me to add to the opcode definitions, which would be located in `binutils/include/opcode/riscv-opc.h` and `binutils/opcodes/riscv-opc.c` if I've built myself the original toolchain.

However in the above prebuilt version I've been struggling to find the necessary header files, since there seems to be no binutils folder in the first place?

The `/opt/riscv` folder where I extracted the whole prebuilt toolchain at looks like the following:

```bash
kveldsstjerne@ubuntu-desktop:/opt/riscv$ ls
bin  include  lib  libexec  riscv64-unknown-elf  share
kveldsstjerne@ubuntu-desktop:/opt/riscv$ ls include/riscv
abstract_device.h                cfg.h     debug_defines.h      decode.h   encoding.h        isa_parser.h  mmio_plugin.h  processor.h  simif.h     vector_unit.h
abstract_interrupt_controller.h  common.h  debug_module.h       devices.h  entropy_source.h  log_file.h    mmu.h          rocc.h       trap.h
cachesim.h                       csrs.h    debug_rom_defines.h  disasm.h   extension.h       memtracer.h   platform.h     sim.h        triggers.h
```

I'm a little confused because this prebuilt version has been built according according to the instructions of [the official RISC-V GNU Compiler Toolchain repository](https://github.com/riscv-collab/riscv-gnu-toolchain).

Any ideas on where the opcode header files would be located at?